# Open set generated by two equivalent norm

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, normed-spaces

Suppose X is an vector space and $||.||_a$ and $||.||_b$ are two norm on it, how i can proof that ''This two norms are equivalent iff they generate same open sets."?

P.S.: Sense of question made by ''Principles of Real Analysis, C.D. Aliprantis, O. Burkinshaw, 3rd Edition, p220.".

Comment: What is your definition of norm equivalence?

Comment: If there exist two constant $K>0$ and $M>0$ such that $K||x||_a\le ||x||_b\le M||x||_a$ holds for each $x\in X$. @ChristopherA.Wong

Comment: And, what is your definition of generating the same open sets (same topology)?  Specifically, what does it mean for a norm to *generate* open sets?

Comment: With each norm we can define a _meter_: $d(x,y) = ||x-y||$, thus we have a metric space $(X,d)$ and in each metric space we have _Opened_ and _Closed_ set. @SammyBlack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy to see that equivalent norms yield the same open sets, because if $K \cdot \Vert x \Vert_a \leq \Vert x \Vert_b \leq M \Vert x \Vert_a$, you have

$$
B_r^{\Vert \cdot \Vert_a}(x_0) \subset B_{r \cdot M}^{\Vert \cdot \Vert_b}(x_0)
$$

and vice versa (show this!).

As a set $U$ is open (w.r.t. $\Vert \cdot \Vert$) iff for each $x \in U$ there is some $\varepsilon >0$ with $B_\varepsilon^{\Vert \cdot \Vert} (x) \subset U$, you should be able to show that $U$ is open w.r.t. $\Vert \cdot \Vert_a$ iff it is open w.r.t. the other norm.

For the converse, note that $B_1^{\Vert \cdot \Vert_a}(0)$ is open w.r.t. the first norm (why?), so by assumption also w.r.t. the second norm.

Thus, there is $\varepsilon > 0$ with

$$
B_\varepsilon^{\Vert \cdot \Vert_b}(0) \subset B_1^{\Vert \cdot \Vert_a}(0).
$$

This should allow you to conclude that $\Vert \cdot \Vert_a \leq \frac{1}{\varepsilon} \Vert \cdot \Vert_b$.